# unknown error: DevTools Active Port file doesn't exist java selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Selenium with Java. Followed online tutorial and tried executing the below code but am getting error message

> unknown error: DevTools Active Port file doesn't exist java selenium.

I surfed on google and added the options arguments but nothing works.

```
package mainfiles;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class MainClass {

    static WebDriver driver;        

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\Latest jar files\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        //options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        driver =new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("www.gmail.com");
        }

}
```

When i run this program, I am getting the below error

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 36409
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.13 seconds
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-6O850P3', ip: '172.20.10.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at mainfiles.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:22)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d)

Comment: Debanjan - I had referred the post which you had mentioned and tried all the solutions provided in that but nothing works.. so thought of asking with new post. You can also see in my code that i had updated my code with the correct answer provided in the post which you had referred. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: in question, i didn't see options are used ex: driver = new ChromeDriver(options); are you tried it?

Comment: Any luck resolving this issue ? we are getting same error on Ubuntu

Comment: What chrome browser version you are using ?

Answer (score 4):

this error is due to the incompatible ChromeDriver version and the Chrome browser version that you are using. Please use the latest Chrome driver.exe (v2.41) with the latest Chrome browser version 68. It has worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

@Samraj Downgrading to Chromedriver 2.38 worked for me on Windows 10 Chrome 66.0.3359.181

Just try **Downgrading or Upgrading** the **Chromedriver versions** according to the page [chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

And download the corresponding versions from this page [chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)